# VHDL Error " Integer literal is not of type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR."

Tags: vhdl

I'm new to VHDL and I'm getting the following error when I try to compile my code:

`** Error: F:\midterm night\assg 3\toplevel_design.vhd(18): near "<byte 0x93>": illegal character found in source`

`** Error: F:\midterm night\assg 3\toplevel_design.vhd(18): near "<byte 0x94>": illegal character found in source`

`** Error: F:\midterm night\assg 3\toplevel_design.vhd(18): Integer literal 0 is not of type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR.`

Seems the problem is `variable memory_block` assignment.

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all; 

entity mem8_16 is 
port( clk,wr_rd : in std_logic;
  din : in std_logic_vector ( 15 downto 0);
  addr : in std_logic_vector ( 2 downto 0);
  dout : out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture memory of mem8_16 is
  signal memory_temp :unsigned (127 downto 0);
begin 
  process(clk,wr_rd)
    variable memory_block: integer range 0 to 7;
  begin
    if (rising_edge(clk))then
      case addr is 
        when “000” => memory_block := 0;
        when “001” => memory_block := 1;
        when “010” => memory_block := 2;
        when “011” => memory_block := 3;
        when “100” => memory_block := 4;
        when “101” => memory_block := 5;
        when “110” => memory_block := 6;
        when “111” => memory_block := 7; 
      end case;
      if (wr_rd ='1') then 
        memory_temp((memory_block * 16 + 15) downto (memory_block * 16)) <= din (15 downto 0);
      end if;
    end if;
    dout <= memory_temp((memory_block * 16 + 15) downto (memory_block * 16));
end memory;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have used some sort of word processor to create your source code, and it has inserted left- and right-double-quote characters (“ - 0x93 and ” - 0x94) rather than a proper ASCII double quote (" - 0x22) as delimiters around your string literals.

Use a code editor to edit code, and use the word processor to edit documentation.

---

Note also that there's no `end` statement for your `process`.

Comment: thx alot but i still have a problem with the line           
    `memory_temp((memory_block * 16 + 15) downto (memory_block * 16)) 
    <= din (15 downto 0);`

Comment: What problem is that?

Comment: Error: F:\midterm night\assg 3\toplevel_design.vhd(28): Target type ieee.std_logic_arith.UNSIGNED in signal assignment is different from expression type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR.

Comment: BTW, this is awfully clunky code for creating an 8x16 memory. Why don't you [use an `array`](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/examples/example-array-type-vhdl.html) like everyone else does? VHDL is already extremely verbose -- why make it worse?

Comment: Exactly what it says: `memory_temp` is declared as `unsigned`. `din` is declared as `std_logic_vector`. You can't assign one to the other without some sort of conversion. But there's no reason for `memory_temp` to be anything other than `std_logic_vector` since that's what `din` and `dout` are.